# Asp Grid Not get odd rowindex

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

When I edit even rows it will match row index as correct as what it is. But when come to odd rows, row index will goes to -1.

```
if (e.Row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Edit)
{
}
```

Comment: Are you using OnRowCommand function?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? When and where are you getting and using that row index?

Comment: Yes, I use the onRowCommand function in  gridview.